# how to do conditional join (if one table could be non-existant)

Tags: sql, join, sas, proc

I have created a macro in which i am joining to several tables using a macro variable in the table name. So, it will be called for different values of that macro variable and do the same processing for them using different table names (basis the macro var). But for a few values one of the tables in the join could be non-existant, then i'd would not want to join to it.

```
 example : /* example code*/
    macro test(cmpnynme,demog,deptt) ;
    proc sql;
    create table final as 
    select a.name,
           b.age,
           c.dept
    from dpt_name_&cmpnynme. a
    inner join demographics_&demog. b on a.dept_id = b.dept_id
    left outer join depart_&deptt. c on a.dept_id = c.dept_id;
    quit;
    %mend;

    %test(a,b,c);
    %test(b,e,f);
    %test(f,g,h); /*Macro calls */
```

Now depart_h does not exist, so in this case i do not want the left join to happen since it's a non_existent table and will return an error in the third macro call.
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use macro logic to conditionally generate the last LEFT JOIN clause. You can test using the EXIST() function.

```
%macro test(cmpnynme,demog,deptt) ;
proc sql;
  create table final as 
    select a.name
         , b.age
         , c.dept
    from dpt_name_&cmpnynme. a
    inner join demographics_&demog. b on a.dept_id = b.dept_id
%if %sysfunc(exist(depart_&deptt)) %then
    left outer join depart_&deptt. c on a.dept_id = c.dept_id
;
  ;
quit;
%mend test;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, this makes sense and gives me some hope, but in my actual query i've got a where clause after this join statements so I cannot put a semicolon post the join statement and otherwise it gives me an error.

Comment: Please ignore my comment above, it worked like a PRO, thanks Tom!!

Comment: The first `;` ends the `%IF` statement and the second one ends the `create` statement. If you have a `where` clause or `order by` clause put them before the `;` that ends the `create` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create query checking the condition and execute it with PREPARE stmt3 FROM @QUERY; EXECUTE stmt3; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;You can concat the query statement checking the respective conditions.

for eg.

```
set @QUERY = '';
IF @conditionOne IS TRUE THEN
SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"left outer join depart_",deptt,". c on a.dept_id = c.dept_id  ");
END IF;
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @QUERY; 
EXECUTE stmt3; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
```

You can run the final query with these statements.
let me know if I am missing the logic.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I guess u've written a T_SQL code here, this is in SAS, so I dont quite understand what is done in your code.

Comment: Actually its query of MySql, you are passing variables through macros,right? We can check the condition from those variables and append the query. Finally the prepared query can be executed. That is what i wanted to show!